# Root finding and Bolzano Theorem

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$, and that $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$. Then it must be $0$ at some point.

How to Mathematically proof this theorem?

This is what I did:

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$, and that $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$.

We now construct two sequences $(a_k)$ and $(b_k)$ through the following procedure:

Let $c_k$ be the midpoint between $a_k$ and $b_k$, i.e. $c_k=(a_k+b_k)/2$.

1) If $f(c_k)<0$, let $a_k+1=c_k$ and $b_k+1=b_k$.
2) If $f(c_k)>0$, let $a_k+1=a_k$ and $b_k+1=c_k$.
3) If $f(c_k)=0$ we have actually found a point between a and b where f is zero, so we are done with the proof for this specific function.

It's now obvious that $(a_k)$ is increasing and that $(b_k)$ is decreasing. Also, $(a_k)$ is bounded above by $b$, and $(b_k)$ is bounded below by $a$. Therefore, by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$, both sequences converge. Since $b_k − a_k \to 0$ they must converge to the same limit, suppose $c$.

Since $f(a_k)<0$ and $f(b_k)>0$ for all $k$, we must have $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(a_k) \leq 0$ and $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(b_k) \geq 0$. But $f$ is continuous, so $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(a_k) = f(\lim_{k \to \infty} a_k)$ and $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(b_k) = f(\lim_{k \to \infty} b_k)$. Both of the last right hand sides equal $f(c)$, leading to $f(c)\leq 0$ and $f(c)\geq 0$, thus $f(c)=0$. Thus we have found a point between $a$ and $b$ where $f$ equals zero.

Comment: Depends on what you already know. Do you know the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: Yes, i know that this is somehow a special case of IVT with f(c)=0.
and I know how to tackle this graphically but don't know how to proof it Mathematically.

Comment: One way to prove this is by Nested intervals taking midpoints

Comment: After you attempt this using Sebastian's hint, let us know whether you succeeded.

Comment: I added what i did.

Comment: @Malik Your proof is correct.

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks